# browsersync no recarga cuando hay cambios en .css

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

browsersync no inyecta el css correctamente, ¿Qué puede estar pasando?, aplique el comando:

```
browser-sync start --proxy localhost/simple-grid --files "./*.*"
```

Hasta ahora me detecta todo tipo de archivo .html .php .js ,pero cuando compila de .scss a .css no hace nada. Como ven tengo 2 consolas, 1 se ejecuta gulp (para compilar sass) y la otra (browser-sync).

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Un saludo!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya probaste que el css no quede en la cache? normalmente el navegador guarda estos archivos para no volverlos a descargar

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si has usado browsersync anteriormente sabrás que esto de la caché no se aplica para esto :D

Comment: A mi lo que me pase es que el browser sync no me carga las imagenes, tienes idea que se debe?